# RecycleView on Fragment using Custom Adapter with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

```
public class AgentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AgentAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<Agent> agentList;
    private Context mContext;

    public AgentAdapter(Context context, List<Agent> agentList) {
        this.agentList= agentList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.agent_row, null);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
        final Agent agent = agentList.get(i);


        //Setting text view title
        customViewHolder.textViewAgentName.setText(agent.getAgentName());
        customViewHolder.textViewAgentPhone.setText(agent.getAgentPhone());
        customViewHolder.textViewAgentRegion.setText(agent.getRegion());
        customViewHolder.textViewAgentStatus.setText(agent.getAgentStatus());

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(agent);
            }
        };
        customViewHolder.textViewAgentName.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != agentList ? agentList.size() : 0);
    }
    public void updateAnswers(List<Agent>agent ) {
        agentList = agent;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView textViewAgentName;
        protected TextView textViewAgentPhone;
        protected TextView textViewAgentRegion;
        protected TextView textViewAgentStatus;


        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.textViewAgentName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentName);
            this.textViewAgentPhone= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentPhone);
            this.textViewAgentRegion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentRegion);
            this.textViewAgentStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentStatus);

        }
    }

    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
```

That's my fragment and this is my Adapter

```
 public class AgentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AgentAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
        private List<Agent> agentList;
        private Context mContext;

        public AgentAdapter(Context context, List<Agent> agentList) {
            this.agentList= agentList;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.agent_row, null);
            CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
            final Agent agent = agentList.get(i);


            //Setting text view title
            customViewHolder.textViewAgentName.setText(agent.getAgentName());
            customViewHolder.textViewAgentPhone.setText(agent.getAgentPhone());
            customViewHolder.textViewAgentRegion.setText(agent.getRegion());
            customViewHolder.textViewAgentStatus.setText(agent.getAgentStatus());

            View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(agent);
                }
            };
            customViewHolder.textViewAgentName.setOnClickListener(listener);

        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (null != agentList ? agentList.size() : 0);
        }
        public void updateAnswers(List<Agent>agent ) {
            agentList = agent;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            protected TextView textViewAgentName;
            protected TextView textViewAgentPhone;
            protected TextView textViewAgentRegion;
            protected TextView textViewAgentStatus;


            public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                this.textViewAgentName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentName);
                this.textViewAgentPhone= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentPhone);
                this.textViewAgentRegion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentRegion);
                this.textViewAgentStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAgentStatus);

            }
        }

        private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
        public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
            return onItemClickListener;
        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        }
```

and this is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
            displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
            return true;
        }

        private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

            //creating fragment object
            Fragment fragment = null;

            //initializing the fragment object which is selected
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.nav_menu1:
                    fragment = new caseFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_menu2:
                    fragment = new testFragment();
                    break;
            }

            //replacing the fragment
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
```

when i tried to open my fragment, the app crashed and the logcat is blank.
previously i could show my json data from activity but now when i tried to use fragment instead, it crashed.

Im using java and android studio.

Anyone know why? Thx in advance.

Comment: You haven't copy-pasted the correct code

Comment: @Naveen im new here, i dont know how to edit my post

Comment: There is an edit option just below the tags after your question.

Comment: @Naveen owh, i see.... thx